# Glassfish 2.1 CLIENT-CERT how to get Principal

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, ssl-certificate

I have a Web application that I want to use with a Client Cert. I have set the following up in my web.xml and I can access my application over https.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

The handshake works fine. I'm only using the cert as a very course grain security measure. I simply wish to know the principal of the supplied cert, no login as such is required. However, when I try to get the principal from the session it's null.

I have also tried

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

but this is null as well. Does anyone know how I can get the principal from my cert?

Many Thanks
Noush

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Glasfish actually requests a client certificate?

I tried to do the same with Tomcat and I found out, that Tomcat only requests a client certificate if you put an `auth-constraint` in your `security-constraint` like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    ...
</security-constraint>
```

Without an `auth-constraint` Tomcat does not need to login the user and so no client certificate needs to be requested. The `transport-guarantee` only forces HTTPS.

But even with this, I had to add the user of the certificate to the container's role management and assign a role to the user, because otherwise the user will not be able to access the URL and gets a HTTP 401 response. So if you just want a client certificate without associating it with a user in the container, it won't work.

In Tomcat you can configure a realm to accept a user without roles when the `role-name` is `*`, but you still have to add the user to the authentication realm, which doesn't help if you want to accept all certificates that are trusted and check the certificate principal yourself. Maybe that is possible with Glasfish.